# How to get visitor's ip address in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, ip, ip-address

I want to retrieve visitor's ip address in Laravel 8 version. Currently I am trying 2 ways but none of them are helping me. When I use these 2 functions, I get ip address like this:

```
::1
```

While I've checked my ip address on google and it is totally different and looks real.

1st Function I am using is:

```
function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }
```

And 2nd is:

```
Request::ip();
```

Anyone can let me know that why it is happening like this and why not the real ip is showing?

Comment: i hope this ::1 is returned in localhost.it will be perfect in your live server

Comment: oh I see. Yes I am on localhost. Maybe this can be the reason. I'll check it after uploading to live server.

Comment: yes I've checked it now and its working after moving to live server. Thanks.